# How to add a CA certificate to libsoup?

Tags: gnome, freebsd, tls, trusted-root-certificates, xfce4

I'm trying to use a small application a (Xfce Weather plugin) behind a corporate firewall. The firewall intercepts HTTPS connections and changes everything to be signed by *their* certificates -- to be able to act as the MiM and watch, what employees are browsing.

I've added the corporate CA's certificate to my Firefox and to what the OS-supplied utilities are using, so those programs do not freak-out.

But this weather plugin uses libsoup, which seems to have its own collection of trusted CA certificates somewhere, and refuses to get the weather updates because it does not trust the firewall's certificate.

How do I add a certificate to libsoup's collection?